# Add new line after adding a new control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I add a new line after each control is added? The control I'm adding to is a table cell.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.ID = "MitchelF" + i.ToString();
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "MitchelF";
    lbl.Font.Size = new FontUnit("18px");
    lbl.ID = "MitchelF" + i.ToString();
    cellUsersPool.Controls.Add(cb);
    cellUsersPool.Controls.Add(lbl);                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert a line-break as an HTML literal via the [`LiteralControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) class :

```
// Add your elements
cellUsersPool.Controls.Add(cb);
cellUsersPool.Controls.Add(lbl);
// Explicitly insert a line break
cellUsersPool.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```